# Prove that a transformation is diagonalizable and find matrix associate to transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm studying a little algebra and I ran into a problem that I haven't been able to solve, and I have no ideas for how to do it.

It is the following:

Let $T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ a linear transformation given by:

1. The eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$
2. $V = \{ (x,y,z) : x - y + z = 0 \}$ is a eigenspace of $T$; and
3. $T(1,1,1) = (-1,-1,-1)$

Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable and find the associate matrix to $T$ with the canonical base.

At the moment, I have obtained 3 linearly independent eigenvectors, but I don't know what to do with them or what other path to choose.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you very much.

Sorry for my English, I'm not native.

Comment: What is a property subspace?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos is a eigenspace, ie, is the space of eigenvectors associate a some of the eigenvalues

Comment: If you have three linearly independent eigenvectors, they form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, and the matrix of $T$ with respect to that basis will be diagonal, so you seem to have solved your question already. Perhaps you could say what the 3 eigenvectors you have found are, and how you found them?

Comment: In order to find the matrix let $$U=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\\ 1&1&1\\ 1& 0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ Then the matrix is equal $UDU^{-1},$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $-1,1,1$ on the main diagonal.

Comment: @krm2233 the three eigenvectors are: $v_1 = (1,1,1)$ by condition 3. Now, it is easy to see that the eigenspace given in 2 corresponds to the eigenvalue 1. Well $v_1 \notin V$. Now we choose a basis of $V$, for example the vectors $v_2 = (1,1,0)$ and $v_3 = (0,1,1)$. Then $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent.

I don't understand why searching for these three vectors is enough, could you give me a little more information? Or some link to read more about it.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc How do you get that matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are happy with the following deduction:

By condition 3 we see that $L=\mathbb R.(1,1,1)^\intercal$ is an eigenline with eigenvalue $-1$. Now condition 2 requires that $V=\{(x,y,z)^\intercal :x-y+z=0\}$ is an eigenspace, and since it does not contain $(1,1,1)^\intercal$, by condition 1, it must be the ($+1$)-eigenspace.

Now $\{(1,1,0)^\intercal, (0,1,1)^\intercal\}$ is  a basis of $V$, hence $\dim(V)=2$, and since $\dim(\mathbb R^3)=3$ and $V \cap L = \{0\}$ it follows that $\mathbb R^3 = L\oplus V$ and hence $\{f_1=(1,1,1),f_2=(1,1,0),f_3=(0,1,1)\}$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $\mathbb R^3$.

Now the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is clearly just
$$
D=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$

The only thing left to do is to figure out how to use this information to write down the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis (which is what I assume is intended by the term "canonical base").
One way to see how to do this is the following: Let
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$
be the matrix whose columns are the vectors $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$. If $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis, then we have
$$
AP = (Af_1|Af_2|Af_3) = (-f_1|f_2|f_3) = PD,
$$
(since if $X$ is any square matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then $XD$ is the matrix obtained by scaling column $i$ of $X$ by the corresponding diagonal entry $d_i$ of $D$). But then $A = PDP^{-1}$ which we can compute directly by inverting $P$. In this case one gets:
$$
PDP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 2 & -2 \\ -2 & 3 & -2\\ -2 & 2 & -1\end{array}\right)
$$